# Problem in Displaying SVG in CSS ::before

Tags: css, svg

I use CSS `::before` to insert images before links.

I am having problems with showing Github SVG. SVG colors do not show properly.

Note: As normal image, the SVG shows fine but as `background` it doesn't.
I have tried no background color, various background colors, as well as transparent.

SVG: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/91/Octicons-mark-github.svg

```css
a[href^="https://github.com/"]::before {
  content: '';
  background: #000 url('../image/github.svg') no-repeat center;
  background-size: contain;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1.1em;
  width: 1.1em;
  margin-right: 0.3em;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
}
```

Any ideas?

**Update: The reason for the problem**

TBH, The above code works as pointed out by @AHaworth

The actual CSS is slightly different and there was the problem.

Actual CSS:

```css
a[href^="https://github.com/"]::before,
/* .... */
a[href^="https://www.mozilla.org/"]::before {
  content: '';
  background: url('../image/dino.svg') no-repeat center;
  background-size: contain;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1.1em;
  width: 1.1em;
  margin-right: 0.3em;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
}

a[href^="https://github.com/"]::before {
  background: url('../image/github.svg') no-repeat center;
}
```

Above does not show the image properly.

However, changing it to the following works fine. It seems `background-size: contain;` needed to be added.

```css
a[href^="https://github.com/"]::before {
  background: url('../image/github.svg') no-repeat center;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

Comment: There is no problem with the github image - it is there just not showing well against a black background. Could you explain what 'SVG colors do not show properly' means as the logo seems to be just dark on transparent background.

Comment: @AHaworth Indeed that is the case and why I am having problem with this particular one. I tried setting fills in SVG, changing bg color but still cant show the image properly. What should I do?

Comment: could you not just give it a white, or some other light, background-color, that worked for me.

Comment: What were you setting? And is there a reason for wanting transparent? I just set background-color: white and saw the logo fine. It's a CSS setting, not an SVG one.

Comment: @AHaworth Thank you for the help. I found out the problem and updated the post in case it might be useful to someone.

Answer (score 3):

It shows the image. the problem is that you use black background. remove the #000

```css
a[href^="https://github.com/"]::before {
  content: '';
  background:  url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/91/Octicons-mark-github.svg') no-repeat center;
  background-size: contain;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1.1em;
  width: 1.1em;
  margin-right: 0.3em;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://github.com/">github</a>
```

Comment: You are using the `.png` version. Can you show it with the .`svg` version?

Comment: I don't think it matters, send a link for the image

Comment: Post already updated.

Comment: @erosman works just fine.  the problem is that you used an image with transparent background and masked black color (the #000) which makes it look like the image is black

Answer (score 1):

Comments seem to indicate there's some misunderstanding so FWIW I put what I did here.

```css
a[href^="https://github.com/"]::before {
  content: '';
  background: pink url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/91/Octicons-mark-github.svg') no-repeat center;
  background-size: contain;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1.1em;
  width: 1.1em;
  margin-right: 0.3em;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://github.com/">Github</a>
```

Note, in this version I set the background color to pink just to show that effects other than just white are possible.